# Query a model through a User model django in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this scenario:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    website = models.URLField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

In my template, I have the `object` object, and I can do this: `{{ object.createdBy }}`

Can I do something like `{{ object.createdBy.userprofile.website }}` in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to your ForeignKey.

```
class Package(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    website = models.URLField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
```

After that you can retrieve user profile for user using name specified in related_name parameter.

```
user = User.objects.select_related('userprofile').first()
profile = user.userprofile
```

In your template it will look like:

```
{{ object.createdBy.userprofile.website }}
```

As mentioned in comments related_name not needed in your situation because it has same name as related model name. From docs:

> If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.

Comment: How will I access the website in my template?

Comment: After adding related_name you can get linked record for you model. In situation with one to one field it's simply object of related model, in situation with many to many and many to one field it will list of objects

Comment: Note that if you didn't retrieve related models using select_related method it will generate additional query for each your user object

Comment: You don't need to set `related_name` for this. The default is already `userprofile`.

Comment: A note for `related_name`: this is really only necessary when your model has 2 `ForeignKey` fields that point to the same model.